# gnome-terminal: change the window geometry from cli

Tags: gnome-terminal

What should I enter inside gnome-terminal to change its current geometry to 80x24?
The same action as GUI's Settings - Advanced - 80x24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize --usehints 80 24
```

```
--usehints
    Use window sizing hints (when available) to set width and height. This is useful
    on terminals for setting the size based on row/column of text rather than pixels.
```

Answer (score 1):

gnome-terminal responds to the control sequences used by xterm's [`resize`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program, letting you do this:

```
resize -s 24 80
```